# Using SSH to allow Internet access

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have two hosts running on separate networks; A win7 machine and a Linux machine. Firewalls on the win7 subnet does not allow access to Internet resources, but it allows access to the Linux machine, and the Linux machine has external access.

I have followed countless tutorials on how to do this, and all of them fail me.

Using PuTTY on the win7 machine, I do something similar to the following:

`ssh -D 4444 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

And inside of IE, I set proxy settings to 127.0.0.1:4444

This is where all tutorial and otherwise documentation on the subject that I have found, ends.

Now, what do I do on the Linux machine? I need to forward requests between the win7 client and the outside world.

Comment: Well, that should be pretty much it. What happens when you try to access a webpage after you set the proxy to localhost:4444 ? Also make sure it is set as a SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy inside your browser.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Nothing happens. It just says IE cannot display the page. Am I not supposed to forward requests from the win7 machine on the Linux machine somehow?

Comment: Well, that's what happens. Requests from the browser are forwarded through the local proxy, which is connected to your Linux machine via SSH. So you constructed an SSH tunnel. I have had success in the past doing this using Firefox and the FoxyProxy plugin. Could you try that? It may just be an IE problem.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Well, what about DNS forwarding? Would I have to do some kind of tunneling in the form of `ssh -L 53:8.8.8.8:53 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to get DNS access on the dynamic forward?

Comment: How DNS requests are resolved depends on the browser's implementation. SOCKS works between the transport layer (TCP/UDP) and the application layer (HTTP/DNS/SSH etc). So in theory you *can* use DNS over SOCKS. However, it seems that IE simply doesn't support this, so even when you set a HTTP proxy, it still tries to resolve DNS requests directly. See https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/956630/support-for-socks-5-and-4a-proxy-settings (also check the link in the comments there).

Comment: With Chromium, however, it seems to work fine: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy. Similarly, Firefox has a setting in `about:config` called `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` which decides whether DNS requests are forwarded through your SOCKS proxy. It's `false` by default, so set it to `true`. If you use the FoxyProxy plugin (as I do), the analog setting is called `extensions.foxyproxy.socks_remote_dns`.

Comment: However, before I experiment with DNS, I would check whether the tunnel actually works without DNS. Try to reach an external IP address from your browser that should be reachable, e.g., http://173.194.116.191/ should be Google. If this works, then your problem is DNS resolving. If it doesn't, you have another problem to solve first, and you can worry about DNS later. As I previously said, definitely try Firefox and Chrome - IE is the *worst* browser to test this, as it has, apparently, very limited SOCKS support.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need `AllowTcpForwarding yes` in `sshd_config`

Comment: Okay, but that still didn't solve anything.